# Async file saving is not executing correctly C#

Tags: c#, file, async-await, save

I've read up a bit on async and await and thought this would be the correct way to execute a file save asynchronously, but it still doesn't seem to be giving me the solution i'm looking for.

I have a program that when prompted will revert a photo to its original, unedited form. This involves an update in the database, followed by deleting the file from the directory and writing the new file to the directory to then be displayed. The problem that arises (to the best of my knowledge) is that it will update and then display before the file is completely written. This doesn't happen every time, but will display the old photo about 60% of the time and when refreshed, will show the correct photo. Here is the current (relevant) code I have for when the revert action happens.

```
 void RevertPhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //Update Database here

      HandleFileAsync();
 }
 async void HandleFileAsync()
    {
        Task<int> task = ResaveFile();
        int count = await task;
        if(count == 1)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //I put this in here to see if it'd fix the issue, but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary.
            PicturePlaceholder.Controls.Clear(); //Clear the pictures on the next page
            GetPhotoInfo(Convert.ToInt32(hiddenICTASKID.Value)); //Reload pictures on next page

            showPanels(PanelPhotoReview); //Show the panel while hiding the rest.
            hidePanels(PanelCleanList, PanelSiteList, PanelImageSwap, Panel5, PanelRevertPhoto, PanelImageDelete);
        }
    }

    async Task<int> ResaveFile()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (File.Exists(RevertFolderPath.Value)) //These two lines shouldn't be necessary as WriteAllBytes will overwrite.
                File.Delete(RevertFolderPath.Value);

            string filePath = RevertFolderPath.Value;
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(Base64RevertImage.Value));
        });
        return 1;
    }
```

Is this the right way to approach it or am I quite a bit off?

Comment: Don't use `async void`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what would be a better approach? I used example 2 from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/

Is it bad to return a variable like i did for int count = await task; ?

Comment: @Nick `async Task HandleFileAsync()` would make it 2000% better - then the caller can `await` it to find out what happened

Comment: Wrap contents of HandleFileAsync in try-catch and see if some exception was thrown. Right now you have no idea if it executed without exceptions or not. As for async void - you can make `HandleFileAsync` return Task, but since `RevertPhoto` is event handler - then it will have to be `async void` anyway.

Comment: @Marc Gravell / Evk If I change the method to async Task HandleFileAsync() and then await HandleFileAsync(); 

Would it then remove the need to have the Handlefileasync() method and I could just run the ResaveFile() method in its place and put the Clear,Load,Show contents (Handlefileasync method) at the end of the RevertPhoto method or is that wrong to assume?

I still don't completely grasp this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code to

```
async void RevertPhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //Update Database here

      await HandleFileAsync();
 }
 async Task HandleFileAsync()
    {
        await ResaveFile();


            PicturePlaceholder.Controls.Clear(); //Clear the pictures on the next page
            GetPhotoInfo(Convert.ToInt32(hiddenICTASKID.Value)); //Reload pictures on next page

            showPanels(PanelPhotoReview); //Show the panel while hiding the rest.
            hidePanels(PanelCleanList, PanelSiteList, PanelImageSwap, Panel5, PanelRevertPhoto, PanelImageDelete);

    }
     async Task ResaveFile()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (File.Exists(RevertFolderPath.Value)) //These two lines shouldn't be necessary as WriteAllBytes will overwrite.
                    File.Delete(RevertFolderPath.Value);

                string filePath = RevertFolderPath.Value;
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(Base64RevertImage.Value));
            });
        }
```

Comment: This unfortunately still provides the save problem.